# Force currency format regardless of input

Tags: php

Regardless of what format the input is in, I am trying to use PHP to modify it, so the output is always consistent, rounds to two decimal places and has a dollar sign. My approach does not yield desired results all the time, I was wondering if someone can help me come up with a more robust solution?

Desired output:

```
$num = "$12.00"; //output   $12.00
$num = "125"; //output   $125.00
$num = "$300"; //output   $300.00
$num = "17.5"; //output   $17.50
$num = "1,777.5"; //output   $1777.50
```

What I tried, however this does not work for all cases:

```
$num = "$" . str_replace("$", "", round($num,0)) . ".00";
```

I appreciate any advice! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num =  "$" . str_replace("$", "", round($num,0));
```

In this line you round before you remove the $-sign. I must be the other way round:

```
$num =  "$" . round(str_replace("$", "", $num),0);
```

EDIT: And to get the output you want, you might want to use number_format() instead of round()

```
$num =  "$" . number_format(str_replace("$", "", $num),2, '.', '');
```

Comment: $num = "$".number_format(str_replace(array("$", ","), "", $num), 2, '.', '');